# Chaining new operator for forwarding chain

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider the below class

```
class Forwarder : public Base
{
private:
     Base* dest;
     Forwarder* next;
public:
    explicit Forwarder(Base* dest, Forwarder* next)
        : dest(dest), next(next) {}
    ~Forwarder() {
        if (next) delete next;
        delete dest;
    }

    void DoStuff() {
        if (next) next->DoStuff();
        dest->Process();
    }
};
```

Its purpose is to create a forwarding chain for events, so if `DoStuff` gets called at the base it will propagate throughout the chain, notifying others. I want to use this for sending output to various streams. Anyway, a typical way to create a chain would be like:

`Forwarder f(new First, new Forwarder(new SomeOther, new Forwarder(new YouGetTheIdea, NULL)));`

This is a really convenient way of constructing a chain, but it's dangerous and vulnerable to memory leaks because the compiler can shuffle things around. Is there a safer way to construct chains like I'm wanting (preferably retaining the lean syntax)?

Comment: What do you mean, because the compiler can shuffle things around?

Comment: @KevinBallard There's no guarantee on the order it will allocate memory in. For example it could allocate `First` and then `SomeOther`, if `SomeOther` throws `First` isn't passed to the constructor and is leaked.

Comment: Maybe you should turn those arguments into `std::unique_ptr`s or `std::shared_ptr`s instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `new` explicitly, use a function which returns a smart pointer, and make the constructors take in smart pointers.

```
For example,

class Forwarder : public Base
{
private:
     shared_ptr<Base> dest;
     shared_ptr<Forwarder> next;
public:
    explicit Forwarder(shared_ptr<Base> dest, shared_ptr<Forwarder> next)
        : dest(dest), next(next) {}

    void DoStuff() {
        if (next) next->DoStuff();
        dest->Process();
    }
};
```

And then use it as so:

```
Forwarder f(make_shared<First>(), make_shared<Forwarder>(make_shared<SomeOther>(), make_shared<Forwarder>(make_shared<YouGetTheIdea>(), shared_ptr<Forwarder>(NULL))));
```

you could also use `unique_ptr` instead, if you implement `make_unique()` (or equivalent factory methods)